# Is all property communal for the monks?

Tags: theravada, monk

The bowl, the robes, the lodgings, the medicines - are these private property, or shared within a Sangha of monks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Theravada Patimokkha](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/vin/sv/bhikkhu-pati-intro.html), it appears that medicines and some other requisites like needle boxes are communal property that shouldn't be kept longer than required.

On the other hand, cloth or wool for robes and an alms bowl which are not determined for personal use, shouldn't be kept for too long, and should be given to communal ownership.

The rules also do not allow keeping more things (in good condition) and bigger things than needed. For e.g. the maximum number of robes, number of alms bowls, size of lodging, furniture in lodging etc. are defined in the rules.

Lodging appears to be for personal use.

This is what I found from reading the [Theravada Patimokkha](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/vin/sv/bhikkhu-pati-intro.html) online, but I do not have direct experience or knowledge of it.

Answer (score 1):

I was a monk for ten years. To answer your question, the answer is no, they are not communal property.